# What is the []byte("") default capacity?

Tags: go

```
s := []byte("")
fmt.Println(cap(s))  //32
```

but

```
s := []byte("")
fmt.Println(cap(s))  //0
fmt.Println(s)
```

Is the compiler does some optimizations?

Comment: I don't believe this is defined in the spec, so the technical answer would be "it's implementation-dependent."

Comment: Are you sure you provided correct example? Both print 32 for me. What is printing 0 i  `s := make([]byte, 0)`

Comment: @jedruniu yeah,i'm sure. I tried in the golang playground. [link](http://play.golang.org/p/pl_BwZTBTS_H)

Comment: Sure, but where do you see in this particular playground `32`?

Comment: Ok, now i Can see it.

Comment: Maybe it's just some shortcut, or bug, look here, for sure this slice has 0 capacity: https://play.golang.org/p/LGp8vpV1_ms

Comment: yes, the go compiler definitely does a lot of optimizations: https://github.com/golang/go/wiki/CompilerOptimizations

Answer (score 0):

It is 0, you have found something peculiar, maybe worth reporting as an issue,

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "reflect"
    "unsafe"
)

func main() {
    s := []byte{}
    hdr := (*reflect.SliceHeader)(unsafe.Pointer(&s))
    fmt.Printf("%#v\n", hdr)

    d := make([]byte, 0)
    hdr = (*reflect.SliceHeader)(unsafe.Pointer(&d))
    fmt.Printf("%#v\n", hdr)

    a := []byte("")
    hdr = (*reflect.SliceHeader)(unsafe.Pointer(&a))
    fmt.Printf("%#v\n", hdr)    
}
```

This always show that capacity is 0.

Comment: it is not an issue, it is an compiler optimization.